# The intersection of two subspaces and the complementary of a $(m-1)$-dimensional subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be two subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^m$ of dimension $d_v > 1$ and $d_w > 1$ with $d_v < d_w$. Furthermore, assume that $\dim V \cap W$ is greater than 1 and less than $d_v$. If $A$ is a subspace of dimension $m-1$ such that:

- $V \cap A^C \ne \emptyset$,
- $W \cap A^C \ne \emptyset$,
- $(V \cap W) \cap A \ne \{0\}$ and
- $V \cap A \not\subset W \cap A$,

then is it true that $(V \cap W) \cap A^C \ne \emptyset$?

Notation: $A^C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^m: x \not\in A\}$.

---

Some of my thoughts:

The question aims to understand (under some further hypothesis) the following natural question: if two subspaces transversal to a subspace $A$ of dimension $m-1$ are transversal to each other when restricted to $A$, then is the intersection of them restricted to the complementary of $A$ non-empty?

I think this is true, but I don't know how to prove it. On the other hand, I accept some comments of possible ideas to prove this (or counterexamples). So feel free to drop a comment about your thoughts on the question.

Comment: Just to confirm, by $\emptyset$ do you mean the empty set, or the zero subspace? Also by $A^C$ do you mean the set theoretic complement of $A$ or the orthogonal complement?

Comment: I made some edits too to clarify this.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^7$, consider $A=\{(0,b,c,d,e,f,g)\}$, $W=\{(a,-a,0,d,e,f,g)\}$, $V=\{(a,0,c,0,0,f,g)\}$.